# Problems with simple calculation

Tags: c

Okay guys just trying to work out why this won't spit out the 0.00003 answer like it's supposed to. Part of a bigger project, will post that if this fix doesn't work for whole project.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define INPUT_C 0.003
#define H_FORWARD_CURRENT  100


int main(void) {
   float ib;
   ib = INPUT_C / H_FORWARD_CURRENT;
   printf("ib = %.5f", &ib);
   return (0);
 }
```

Comment: the include is the stdio.h library and the defines both have # tags

Answer (score 6):

Because you're trying to print the address of `ib` as a float:

```
 printf("ib = %.5f", &ib);
```

Should be

```
printf("ib = %.5f", ib);
```

Comment: The sad thing is, the compiler would have told the OP this if he had enabled warnings.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Yeah, another good example of why one should always compile with `-Wall -Wextra` at least.

Answer (score 3):

you don't need to add ampersand `&` operato before `ib`  in printf

```
printf("ib = %.5f", &ib);
                    ^ wrong
```

correct it like:

```
printf("ib = %.5f", ib);
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove & from &ib in printf().

```
printf("ib = %.5f", ib);
```